# How can I disable GPU rendering in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm with bad rendering issues... Seems that the Visual Studio Code window do not clean a screen area before redraw it. The same thing happens here with chrome browser, but in chrome I can start it with " --disable-gpu-rendering " and it goes well.

How can I disable GPU rendering in Visual Studio Code ?

I'm thinking it's a hardware specific problem, and I'm looking for a other way to solve it too.

May be useful know my hardware:

```
Machine: Notebook dell vostro 3500 (intel chipset)
CPU: Intel i5
RAM: 8G
linux kernel: 4.0
video graphics: intel i915 (latest)
X -version: X.Org X Server 1.14.0
```

Comment: My Notebook has Dell HD Graphics 5500 also supported by i915 driver. It used to work, but start to malfunction after a system reinstall. I'm just about to disbale gpu, but it start to function after  update `libegl1-mesa` and the related ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under Windows, I can confirm that launching VSCode with `--disable-gpu` does not create a GPU process:

`C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0>Code.exe --disable-gpu`

Perhaps the same flag works on Linux too?

Comment: See @VonC 's answer for a more up to date solution.

Comment: I landed here and concur @VonC is the solution!

Answer (score 141):

Note that [VSCode 1.40 (Oct. 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration) proposes an alternative to the parameter/flag `--disable-gpu`:

> ### Disable GPU acceleration

> We have heard issue reports from users that seem related to how the GPU is used to render VS Code's UI.
> These users have a much better experience when running VS Code with the additional `--disable-gpu` command-line argument.
> Running with this argument will disable the GPU hardware acceleration and fall back to a software renderer.
>
> **To make life easier, you can add this flag as a setting so that it does not have to be passed on the command line each time**.
>
> To add this flag:
>
> - Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
> - Run the `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` command.
>   This command will open a `argv.json` file to configure runtime arguments.
>   You might see some default arguments there already.
> - Add
>
>   ```
>   "disable-hardware-acceleration": true
>   ```
> - Restart VS Code.
>
> Note: Do not use this setting unless you are seeing issues!

---

Note that [Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10030693/gilbert) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code/58762168?noredirect=1#comment126634547_58762168) to "**[How To Fix Screen Flickering Issue On Mac, MacBook, And iMac](https://wethegeek.com/how-to-fix-screen-flickering-issue-on-mac-macbook-and-imac/)**" from **[Preeti Seth](https://twitter.com/preetiseth)**.

Gilbert adds:

> I fixed the problem by disabling automatic graphics switching on my macbook pro.
> The setting is located in `system preferences -> battery`.
> It worked!

Comment: I was experiencing mini video crashes so I gave this a try, amazingly not only the crashes were fixed, but my load times with remote wsl reduced by 10x, I thought that vs code was just slow to load lol, thanks

Comment: much better solution than the command parametr which is not possible to use in many cases. it helps with high gpu use bug.

Comment: None of the options on this page worked for me and my macbook. So I decided to use intellij instead of vscode but atleast I was able to narrow down the macbook flickering problem as being caused by vscode

Comment: I fixed the problem by disabling automatic graphics switching on my macbook pro. The setting is located in system preferences -> battery . It worked! https://wethegeek.com/how-to-fix-screen-flickering-issue-on-mac-macbook-and-imac/

Comment: @Gilbert Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly in VS Code 1.69 by adding `disable-hardware-acceleration`  param and I just realized there is GPU hardware problem in my PC..

Comment: Lifesaver. After blaming Linux Mint, VMWare Player, Windows 10, and a yet-to-be-identified malware infection I finally tried this. Voila! Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu, the file to edit is `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`.

Change:

`Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F`

to:

`Exec=/usr/share/code/code --disable-gpu --unity-launch %F`

Comment: P.S. you're going to have to redo this every time you upgrade to a new version. I have complained to their dev team but they punted it.

Comment: you can override launchers here `$HOME/.local/share/applications`

Answer (score 7):

### For Windows users

Visual studio code is based on chrome, to make it work you'll have to disable hardware acceleration.

Add `--disable-gpu --disable-gpu-compositing` to the vs code shortcut on your desktop.

[image]

**Example:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu --disable-gpu-compositing
```

Comment: You state that VS Code is based on Chrome. Do you happen to have a link to more information about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

on Mac running in virtualbox you can edit the file in `~/.vscode/argv.json`

- Add

  `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`

Comment: This also worked in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

macOS users can try the following commands in the terminal :

Goto Applications folder :

`cd Applications`

Open VS Code with GPU Disabled :

`Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --disable-gpu`

Note : You might need to supply `sudo` with second command.

Answer (score 2):

Inside settings.json you can write this:-

```
"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint I had to right click the lower left mint button, then choose configure, then press the menu button. Then press the "Open Menu Editor" button and find Visual Studio Code in the programming group. Click properties and find the command field. There you can set the --disable-gpu option.

Answer (score 0):

If environment variables are mapped correctly, you can simply use cmd.exe to start an instance of *code* with **--disable-gpu** . See the screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8wCO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is caused by automatic graphic switching as the computer tries to save energy.

In my case my macbook pro has battery problems so they manifested as the screen flickering whenever I ran an intensive application like vscode.

To disable automatic graphic switching, go to system preferences -> battery and untick `Automatic graphic switching`.

Refer to this guide: https://wethegeek.com/how-to-fix-screen-flickering-issue-on-mac-macbook-and-imac/