# Electron Apps - Weird Graphical Artifacts, Glitch?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm using VSCode or Postman, this happens:

[image: weird graphical glitch 2]

[image: weird graphical glitch 2]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Browsing the vs-code section, I realize that it has to do with the gpu. Disabling gpu rendering solved the graphical glitch:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762168/9246191

Comment: This is happening to me in Slack, GitKraken and VS Code (all Electron apps). Slack has an advanced preference to disable GPU rendering. No setting as yet for GitKraken.