# Why does my VSCode randmonly have white frost looking lines around icons in explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons

Randomly when I am working, VSCode will have white lines that look like frost around my icons. It goes away when I click on something, but it is very odd and distracting. I have attached a picture showing what is happening. What is this from, and how can I get rid of it?

[image: Frost on icon]

Comment: There have been multiple question with this rendering behaviour

Comment: Can you link me to any of these other questions? I tried to search for one, but I could not find any because I was not sure how to describe the issue without a picture.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this and see if you could point me to another question talking about this.

Comment: I remember it could have to do with GPU and maybe only on MacOS. It can have to with GPU rendering try `code --disable-gpu`. Then I found one of the posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015048/electron-apps-weird-graphical-artifacts-glitch