# My VS code is bugging out (graphical glitches)

Tags: visual-studio-code

The screen would suddenly freeze, and these white crystals would start growing around my screen (only in vs code). This started happening today. Pictures are included.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These pics are odd and really beautiful at the same time. Either it's hardware-related or a viral issue. Are you sure it only affects VSCode, are you able to move and close your window, and what does your screen show aside of it ?

Comment: ya its only vscode. I have tried to re install it, but its still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron Apps - Weird Graphical Artifacts, Glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015048/electron-apps-weird-graphical-artifacts-glitch)