# Graphical glitches/artifacting in Visual Studio Code on Windows 11

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-11

[image]

As you see, some of the programs on Win 11 are sometimes blurred.

VSC, Exodus, Discord etc.

Comment: Hey Jaden, please [edit] your title to make it more representative of your problem. As it is currently, it would be difficult for others with the same problem to find this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron Apps - Weird Graphical Artifacts, Glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015048/electron-apps-weird-graphical-artifacts-glitch)

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Nvidia GPU try turning off `low latency mode`, if the issue still persists then disable `hardware acceleration` in visual studio code

Comment: I turned off low latency mode on the Nvidia GPU setting but didn't work. However, the disabling hardware acceleration solved the problem on VSC. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. Funny enough, I was having this same issue but with a virtualization of Ubuntu on Virtual Box. On the display settings of said virtual machine, untick the "Enable 3D Acceleration" and voilá!