# Visual Studio Code Looks Fuzzy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

i'm facing a problem where my vscode contents will looks blurry when a notification shows up. And only fixed when i move app (alt+tab), Thank You. [Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVyT9.jpg)

I already tried re-install my vscode but it didn't work, Help me pls, this is so annoying >:0

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron Apps - Weird Graphical Artifacts, Glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015048/electron-apps-weird-graphical-artifacts-glitch) Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425855/graphical-glitches-artifacting-in-visual-studio-code-on-windows-11

Comment: Yes thank you guys, love y'all @TimothyG.