# Does anyone know why my vscode is behaving like this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Why is my vscode ui being like this? I tried completely uninstalling and installing vscode but the issue remains same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1tw5.jpg)

Tried completely uninstalling and installing but issue remains same

Comment: Looks like either a GPU issue or Screen Issue. Not sure why the top left corner of an application would be impacted.

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron Apps - Weird Graphical Artifacts, Glitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015048/electron-apps-weird-graphical-artifacts-glitch)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **theme color** of your vsCode editor. And check that by mistake any unknown **extension** downloaded by you or not.
Other side there might be problem in your display of computer check that onece.

There is one way also,
You can completely delete old vscode version files.

Comment: Disabling gpu acceleration solved the issue. Thanks for your time.