# WPF designer performance with complex user controls

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019

We are using Visual Studio 2019's WPF XAML to build a user interface for a Windows-10 desktop application.  The user interface for the app has become "heavy" with a number of complex user controls placed on it.

The XAML designer has now become extremely bogged down and consumes the bulk of CPU processing (often >75%).  This causes intolerable delays and freeze-ups even while doing simple tasks such as editing XAML text.

Is this...

(1) a known issue with a documented fix,

(2) a known issue that we just need to live with until it gets fixed by Microsoft, or

(3) an unknown issue (likely caused by our code implementation and not the WPF designer)?

Comment: 2) likely. You may disable the designer under Tools->Options->XAMl Designer and learn how to write XAML :)

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly and is what we do. It will be a very difficult sell to our anti-C# (pro-LabView) colleagues.  I appreciate the suggestion though - I should have mentioned we do that.

Comment: Designer is useful for seeing layout/render results before run-time and for quick navigation. I am curious how does currently UI looks like in designer, because either you are too much mimicing run-time or not splitting views enough. Since question is not tagged with MVVM I suspect second and solution is to start using MVVM and splitting more, e.g. complex listview/datagrid can be moved into dedicated user control/another viewmodel.

Comment: > "too much mimicing run-time"  - yes, it mimics runtime exactly.  I was unaware this could be an issue.  I have unsuccessfully tried to find a setting to disable rendering of user controls in the XAML designer.  Is that possible?  We are using MVVM, but I didn't recognize that as relevant to the issue so I didn't mention it.  Thanks Sinatr.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code) may give you some help to disable rendering.