# How do I get rid of these white boxes on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Even changed color themes multiple times, restarted computer. The white boxes move around when i click on another line of my code. Like if I click in the middle of the box, it moves down and avoids that line. How do I get rid of these white boxes?  they only appear in open editors

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Carcigenicate it seems to expand and contract with the size of the window. Currently, its around 30 characters

Comment: try with all extensions disabled and with your settings.json files removed/renamed (global and workspace)

Comment: @rioV8 just tried that. they're still there

Comment: I've tried visual studio code, but it's so bad to me that I'd rather use vim.

Comment: Encountered the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73075737/2925494). It can be fixed by [Disabling GPU rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762168)