# How to get rid of strange lighter spots on the Visual Studio Code interface?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

How to get rid of these strange lighter boxes in the Visual Studio Code interface?

[image: visual code interface rectangles]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Disabling GPU rendering in Visual Studio Code fixed it. Follow this [Disable GPU acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762168)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).