# how to capture window in windows 10 with c++

Tags: window

I tried use gdi to capture certain window, it's ok for most window.
But to some window like "visual studio code", it doesn't work.
DX can't support capturing certain window.
How should I do? THANKS

```
    ::EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    if (hCapWnd == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    SwitchToThisWindow(hCapWnd, true);
    Sleep(1000);
    //HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetWindowDC(hCapWnd);
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hCaptureDC, COLORONCOLOR);
     RECT rc;
    ::GetWindowRect(hCapWnd, &rc);
    int width = rc.right - rc.left;
    int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;
     HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, width, height);
     SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);
     BOOL bRet = BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
     Init(width, height);
     int nRet = GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0, height, buf, (BITMAPINFO*)&m_bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    static int n = 0;
    //if (n++ % 10 == 0) 
    {
       // std::string name = ustd::format_string("%s\\%d.bmp", ustd::get_program_path().c_str(), n);
        SaveBitmapToFile(hCaptureBitmap);
    }

    ReleaseDC(hCapWnd, hDesktopDC);
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
```

Comment: Did you try to disable gpu of Visual Studio Code ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: you are right. If I disable gpu, then it's ok. But how should I can capture the window if gpu is available.