# Runtime Argument for No Sandbox

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have to run VS Code using `code --no-sandbox` as I face issues in loading webviews if I run it via the exe or just `code` without the arguments.

Is there a way to do this by default, just like there is runtime argument for *disable hardware acceleration* which can be put in `argv.json` or any other way by which I can bypass entering that command?

Comment: see also [What arguments are supported in VS Code's argv.json file?](/q/77249826/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

looking for disable in the launch args, there's a candidate..

```
            "--disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion",
```

but then saw reference to another argument in "disable GPU rendering"
[How can I disable GPU rendering in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code)

searched vscode repo for disable-gpu , found a flag you may be after, at
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5526326c496692c63aef2ced1e30fd4f50d69b8d/src/vs/platform/environment/common/argv.ts#L126

```
'disable-gpu-sandbox'?: boolean;
```

so adding "disable-gpu-sandbox": true
to your settings may do it

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Instead, I can confirm the same behavior as seen here under Arch Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72518507/5885566