# Can't start Visual Studio Code in root, how do I do this

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use popOS, an Ubuntu OS

I keep getting an error that says "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument `--no-sandbox` and specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument."

I need to run Visual Studio Code in Root so that I can edit a website I am working on

How can I get around this error and run Visual Studio Code as Root?

Here's some code from the program

```
# If root, ensure that --user-data-dir or --file-write is specified
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    for i in "$@"
    do
        case "$i" in
            --user-data-dir | --user-data-dir=* | --file-write )
                CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT=1
            ;;
        esac
    done
    if [ -z $CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT ]; then
        echo "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument \`--no-sandbox\` and specify an alternate user data directory using the \`--user-data-dir\` argument." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't use VSC, but as it says, running as root is not recommended, so why exactly do you want to do this? Why do you need root access to edit a website? In any case, if you *do* need root, the error message says exactly what you need to do, so what do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Very good question! I have the same issue, VSC just keeps complaining regardless of the `--no-sandbox` flag and refuses to launch when providing `--user-data-dir /home/$USER`. (If you are aware of the dangers, using VSC as root can be quite handy, e.g., for editing system config files without dealing with vim and editors alike.)