# VSCode doen't show any text at all

Tags: visual-studio-code, nixos

Well... This is a rather strange bug I have.
I'm on NixOS using I3. I just did a `nix flake update` and rebuilt the system with `nixos-rebuild switch`. And now, my VSCode doesn't show any more text.

But I can click on things and everything seems to work... I just don't have any more text.
[image]

[Here](https://github.com/0nyr/nixos-config) is my system NixOS config.

I tried looking at the logs in `~/.config/Code/logs` but didn't find anything interesting.
I have no clue what the problem could be or how to fix it... Any help welcome.

Comment: Disable hardware acceleration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: It might be related wiith GPU. Try to disable using GPU in VSCode

Comment: I did that, adding "disable-hardware-acceleration": true, into argv.json... nothing changed ?

Comment: Solution: """If you are affected by this issue, the current workaround is to delete the GPU cache located at ~/.config/Code/GPUCache."""