# In VSC and other apps, when i scroll the text becomes black and turns normal after a very short delay 100ms. It is really annoying

Tags: visual-studio-code, hardware, text-editor, hardware-acceleration

When i open up VSC and other apps the text on  the editor, extension page etc. turns black and reappears after a very short time. This issue is not version related as i have this for over 6 months. Please help.

I have tried disabling anti aliasing FXAA for NVIDIA Graphics drivers but that didnt make a difference. I have also disabled terminal GPU acceleration

Comment: does this happen in other chromium/electron apps like discord app, MS teams app, chrome, etc.? what if you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762168/11107541 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: sounds like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194919. try https://stackoverflow.com/q/29966747/11107541